# Observing frequent set_autocommit = ? and db.SQL.innodb.rows mysql spikes with springboot mysql 5 with 3 pod deployment

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Observing high number of set_autocommit = ?
Observing peoridic (20 mins) spike in rds performance insight

Running versions:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.26.0"
id "com.palantir.docker-run" version "0.26.0"
id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.13.2'
id 'com.appland.appmap' version '1.1.0'
```

3 pods running on aws eks
db -> aws rds 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.1

Here are the configurations:
application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xyz
  profiles:
    # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
    # Otherwise, it will be filled in by gradle when building the JAR file
    # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
    active: dev
    group:
      dev:
        - dev
        - api-docs
        # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
        #- tls
      prod:
        - prod
        - api-docs
        # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
        #- tls
      stage:
        - stage
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 20
        max-page-size: 20
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: deferred
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true #https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: true
      hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy: create
      # modify batch size as necessary
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 20
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
      hibernate.order_updates: true
      hibernate.batch_versioned_data: true
      hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch: true
      hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding: true
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      javax.persistent.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  task:
    execution:
      thread-name-prefix: xyz-task-
      pool:
        core-size: 2
        max-size: 50
        queue-capacity: 10000
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: catalogue-scheduling-
      pool:
        size: 2
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML
  output:
    ansi:
      console-available: true

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true
  tomcat:
    mbeanregistry:
      enabled: true
    threads:
      max: 100
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json"
    min-response-size: 1024
  port: 8080

# Properties to be exposed on the /info management endpoint
info:
  # Comma separated list of profiles that will trigger the ribbon to show
  display-ribbon-on-profiles: 'dev'

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info,metrics,prometheus"
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      show-details: always
      show-components: always
```

application-prod.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.hibernate.SQL: ERROR
    com.pitstop.catalogue: INFO
    com.zaxxer.hikari: INFO
  config: classpath:logback-prod.xml

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  datasource:
    auto-commit: false
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
      poolName: CatalogJPAHikariCP
      minimumIdle: 10
      maximumPoolSize: 120
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 600000
      maxLifetime: 1800000
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        testWhileIdle: true
        validationQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
        useLocalSessionState: true
        rewriteBatchedStatements: true
        cacheResultSetMetadata: true
        cacheServerConfiguration: true
        maintainTimeStats: true
  servlet:
    multipart:
      location: /data/tmp
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      spring.jpa.show-sql: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
  liquibase:
    contexts: prod
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
```

Example of one entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_model")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ProductModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"productModels"}, allowSetters = true)
    private ProductMake productMake;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productModel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product", "productModel"}, allowSetters = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<ProductModelMapping> productModelMappings = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ProductMake getProductMake() {
        return this.productMake;
    }

    public void setProductMake(ProductMake productMake) {
        this.productMake = productMake;
    }

    public Set<ProductModelMapping> getProductModelMappings() {
        return this.productModelMappings;
    }

    public void setProductModelMappings(Set<ProductModelMapping> productModelMappings) {
        if (this.productModelMappings != null) {
            this.productModelMappings.forEach(i -> i.setProductModel(null));
        }
        if (productModelMappings != null) {
            productModelMappings.forEach(i -> i.setProductModel(this));
        }
        this.productModelMappings = productModelMappings;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof ProductModel)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((ProductModel) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductModel{" +
                "id=" + getId() +
                ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
                "}";
    }

}
```

One of the JPA repo:

```
@Repository
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Brand> {
}
```

One of the service methods:
I keep @Transactional at service class level
Do not keep @Transactional on save / update service layer methods

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<BrandDto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all Brands");
    return baseService.findAndBuild(pageable, brandRepository);
}



@Override
public Page<T> findAndBuild(Pageable pageable, JpaRepository<E, K> repository) {
    final Page<E> pageEntityResponse = repository.findAll(pageable);
    return pageConverter(pageEntityResponse);
}
```

Couple of Issues that I am facing is :

1. lot of set_autocommit = ? being fired
   [image]
2. db.SQL.innodb.rows mysql spikes in every 20 minutes interval
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you’ve got AppMap enabled.

You may try the option `appmap.recording.auto`  as described at https://appland.com/docs/reference/appmap-java.html.

Start your server, let it run for a bit, shut it down and you should see those queries being issued (by the connection pool, I suspect). You can include the package names of the connection pool, ORM, and database driver in your `appmap.yml` if you want to extra detail.

Additional help is available in Discord - https://discord.com/invite/N9VUap6